# C# - Reading Serial Port values while processing another method

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, interface, serial-port

I am completely new to C# and I have a pretty simple problem that I can't figure out.
I am trying to improve an existing code that I don't fully understand.

My program connects to a device using the Serial port when pressing a "Connect" button :

```
 private void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort.PortName = (string)comboBox_SerialPorts.SelectedItem;
        serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
    }
```

The method SerialPort_DataReceived handles the DataReceived event :

```
    public delegate void InvokeTreatment(byte[] buffer);
    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[13];
        try
        {
            serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            byte tmp = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                tmp += buffer[i];
            if ((buffer[11] == tmp) && (buffer[12] == '!'))
                try
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeTreatment(Treatment_UART), new object[] { buffer });
                }
                catch { }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The Treatment_UART is a function that uses the values from the Serial Port to display values on my interface.

```
private void Traitement_UART(byte[] buffer)
```

At this point, my program works correctly : It displays in real-time the values received from my Serial device.

I now want to do some processing in another method called "*Processing*" that starts when pressing a button (for example a long for loop that processes data received from the Serial device). 
My problem is that, during *Processing* execution, the real-time receiving and displaying of the Serial values is not anymore active. I need my program to keep receiving information from the Serial device during the execution of *Processing*.

There might be different ways to do that. I thought about running my function in another thread, or simply calling the "SerialPort_DataReceived" method inside my *Processing* method... 
How should I do that ? Maybe running *Processing* in another thread implies risks of reading incorrect (or not actualized) values from the Serial port ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have included the answer in your tags! Are you then asking for an example of running a method on a different string?

Comment: I am asking which way is the best (calling the method inside Processing or using different thread) and maybe an example or hints on how to achieve that...

Comment: You're definitely going to need a new a thread for that. Your current thread is busy listening to your serial-port so it cannot complete any other tasks. I included an example for you in my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To multithread make sure you're using the `using System.Threading;` at the top then simply do this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(yourFuntionHere(params));
thread.Start();
```

The thread will close itself after the method is complete, so no need to worry about that!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My method "Processing" is an event handler of a button_Click... Does this part have to be included inside the method ?

Comment: Okay you should take  the guts of your event handler `Processing` and cut-paste them into a newly made function. Then have `Processing` create the thread that calls that newly made function. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense perfectly. Thanks a lot for your answer. My only remaining problem is that my event handler needs to print text in a TextBox, but I get the following error : `'Invalid inter-thread operation: The' textBox_state_measure 'control was accessed from a thread other than the one on which it was created.'`
I don't remember creating my TextBox in a specific thread ...

Comment: No problem! Okay so technically your textbox has been created on the first thread. Imagine thread1 has built your form, finished that, and is now reading in serial data. That's why textbox belongs to thread1. It is best practice to make any changes/updates to the GUI with the same thread that it was created on. For this reason I'm going to suggest you _instead listen to your serial port on the new thread2_ and have your button click stay on thread1. **close to char limit so I'm continuing in a new comment for you**

Comment: However, if you want you can sort of hack this and use a background thread instead and keep your serial listening on thread 1. You'll need to do some searches like `Changing GUI from background worker thread c#` but you should find some good examples. Sorry I'm not rehearsed in using the background worker. I used it once, let me go through my old code 1 sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I managed to print the values on my textbox! I now have some other problems, I guess it's related to thread confusion, but I will try to figure it out :)

Comment: Good to hear bud. If you're still having issues with this and can't seem to get it, let me know and we'll see if we can work it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. There are multiple ways to solve the problem but probably the most straightforward is the `BackgroundWorker` class. (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)